# when will libcurl close the socket which is opened by OPEN_SOCKETFUNCTION open_callback?

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

I saw the [CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION.html) callback documented in libcurl.

The function is described to be used as:

```
int closesocket_callback(void *clientp, curl_socket_t item);
curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_CLOSESOCKETFUNCTION, closesocket_callback);
```

and it says: `item` is the socket libcurl wants to be closed.

In what kind of condition will libcurl call this closesocket_callback? The document doesn't describe this completely.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply when it is done using the socket for the desired transfer. Sockets are used for network operations and when libcurl is done with its doings it cleans up after itself and closes the open sockets again.

The close callback gets called instead of `close()` if set.